# How To Pass Integrated Authentication User on to Another Web Service Using WCF Web Api

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, wcf-web-api

I have the following setup:

Intranet Application --> Call WCF Web Api --> Calls Autonomy Worksite Web Server

The call to the worksite web server must be from the authenticated active directory user making the call to the intranet application.

So I guess I'm hoping I can pass the credential on to the WCF Web service, which can then use them to make the web service call.

Is this possible?  Or should I ask the user to enter his / her password.......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd want to configure contrained Kerberos delegation in Active Directory, in order to pass the original callers credentials to the WCF application.

[How to: Use Delegation for Flowing the Original Caller Credentials to the Back End in WCF Calling from Windows Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650896.aspx)

Comment: This looks like it may do the trick... I've stalled on it for the time being but will let you know once I have a go!  Thanks again.